# C What is up with my Matrix Reader?

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, malloc, points

so I am trying to make a matrix reader that will take a text file that contains only data for a NxN matrix such as:

```
10 9 8 7
6 5 4 3
2 1 0 1
```

Read the test file into a dynamic multidimensional array. The program will not have headers, so it will need to read the entire file in order to obtain # of rows/cols.

Once I have all the data in my array I then will be able to manipulate how I want (i.e. swapping columns/rows, reversing order, etc).

At this point I am just trying to get my program to simply output the array as it appears in the test file once the entire matrix has been read in.

Here is what I have written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int n;
  int i=0;
  int j=0;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  int **array;
  array = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));

  if(array == NULL) {
    printf("Out of memory\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    array[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if(array[i] == NULL) {
      printf("Out of memory\n");
      exit(1);
    }

  }

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      int k;
      scanf("%d", &k);
      array[i][j] = k;
      printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

And running this gives me output:

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1... repeating 1's...
```

I am not sure what is wrong with my code I have been staring at it for a solid hour and have made 0 progress.

Because my output prints out about 100 different ints I feel that my problem lies in my printing loops, and I feel like it has something to do with int n, but I am not sure how to deal with this.

Any help with be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What's the input for this output ? Also, the matrix you provided as an example is not NxN.

Comment: Is your standard input `stdin` redirected, or are you entering these numbers to your console yourself?

Comment: chrk, This program needs to work for any dimensions. So NxM I suppose.
ThoAppelsin, I am using bash console to run this. So I will have a file created [matrix] and then "./matrixReader < matrix".

Comment: @Blued00d I am not familiar with such Linux-specifics, but as far as I know, that indeed is a way of redirecting standard input.

Comment: Yes I am redirecting input, do you see any issues that I may have because of this?

Comment: The reason why I was wondering if the `stdin` was being redirected, is that if it was not redirected, then it would ask for you to input further numbers to fill up the remaining `10 * 10 - 11 = 89` slots; unlike when you have a file-redirected one, in which case (also in your case) it just gives up and starts returning `EOF`s without making any assignments.

Comment: size at the beginning of the file to be read for `scanf("%d", &n);`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is as follows: The first number that is obtained from your file is `10` and that is being stored inside the `int n` close towards the beginning. That value defines the width and height of your multi-dimensional array, your matrix. You then ask for further values from that file, exactly `10 * 10` many times.

The file, however, only has `4 * 3 - 1 = 11` numbers left in it. It provides them all, right into the `int k`. Those values get stored inside your matrix, printed. After the 11th (or 12th if you count the first `10`) the `scanf` starts failing. As it fails, it returns the value `EOF == -1` but you do not recognize that.

Failure leaves the `k` as it is, although I am not sure whether it is guaranteed to remain what it previously was, since as far as I know, `k` could very well have another memory location allocated for itself with each cycle, since (again) as far as I know it gets cleared at the end of each loop. In your case, it does keep its value, luckily I would say, and that gets stored/printed.

In the end, you should have exactly 100 numbers printed, because of that `10` at the very beginning.

Even if you had an additional `4` at the very beginning, you'd end up with a matrix that has a wild last line with all `1`s.

If you want to have a 3 by 4 matrix in your hands, consider making your file as the following example:

```
3 4
10 9 8 7
6 5 4 3
2 1 0 1
```

Then read the first value into an `int n` and then second one into an `int m`. Make first memory allocation with `malloc( n * sizeof * array );`, then the secondary allocations with `malloc( m * sizeof ** array );`.

You could also alternatively omit reading anything, deduce how many rows and columns your matrix should have by reading the amount of new-line `'\n'` occurrences in your file (plus one), as well as amount of numbers there are on a single line.

### Edit:

Okay, let's show this *you could also* part: This is just an example, I'll be using a pair of `scanf`s for counting both the amount of lines that have at least one number inside and amount of numbers on a single line.

```
...
int n = 0;
int m = 0;
int discardable;

while ( scanf( "%d", &discardable ) == 1 ) {
// as long as a number has been successfully read
    n++;

    if ( scanf( "%*[^\n]" ) != 0 )
    // discard everything until a '\n'
    // and if you fail to encounter a '\n' anywhere until the file ends...
        break;
}

// rewind back to the beginning of the file
rewind ( stdin );

while ( scanf( "%d", &discardable ) == 1 ) {
// as long as a number has been successfully read
    m++;

    if ( scanf( "%*[ \t]" ) != 0 || stdin->_ptr[0] == '\n' )
    // discard every ' ' or '\t'
    // if you rather get carried until the end of file, break
    // else, if the upcoming character is '\n', again, break
        break;
}

rewind ( stdin );
...
```

There you have it, `n` and `m` here should be storing the height and width of the matrix you should have, respectively.

This is just a way to do it, I can see why many could potentially just hate this, because I have made use of the `FILE` structure, and referred to `_ptr`, but whatever. I personally would prefer this any day over carrying a temporary character array and read from it.

Comment: I am not using headers, so that won't work. As far as that alternative goes, I am not sure on how to achieve that besides something like.. getchar, and that would not work with any ints that use more than 1 char of space (or at least I'm not that familiar with getchar to do that).

Comment: @Blued00d Dude, the word *header* means something very specific in C, I could not know what you could have meant by that until now. I hope I won't be doing anything bad with this, but I will go ahead and show you how you could do it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by doing anything bad? This isn't homework or assignment or something if you were thinking that. Just messing around cause I need to learn tabular manipulation and this is how I get there :)

Comment: @Blued00d Still, an exercise is an exercise, whether it has been given by someone or yourself. I hope this expands your view instead, contrary to restricting it.